# How to make Logitech trackball wheel scroll a full page instead of three lines?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I recently migrated to Ubuntu from Windows. On Windows, the device's (vertical) scrolling can be changed via a drop down box but no such thing shows up on Ubuntu **System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad**.

I read that a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` directory needs modification but that advice relates to the Logitech marble mouse. I don't know how to go beyond this, here are the files in there.

```
10-evdev.conf             50-vmmouse.conf
10-quirks.conf            50-wacom.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf      51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  glamoregl.conf
50-synaptics.conf
```

OS & trackball details:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop
- [Logitech Cordless Optical Trackman](http://support.logitech.com/product/cordless-trackman-optical)

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer to my own question:

Follow video at http://www.nicknorton.net

Install imwheel (`sudo apt install imwheel`), then download http://www.nicknorton.net/mousewheel.sh.

*imwheel* displays a little slider, you change the setting to around 15 to get a full page.